# How to distribute and swap business logic at runtime?

Tags: module, clojure, jvm, java-platform-module-system

I have experience in swapping business logic in .NET by loading assemblies, and using reflection to find an implemented interface. This enabled behaviour composition at runtime, by simply distributing and placing DLL files into its working directory. How can I achieve the same in Clojure?

I have been informed I could compile my Lein project without AoT compilation, with dependency on a class which the JVM will search for I assume from sibling JAR files? I've also seen Java 9 has a solution called "Jigsaw", and there other projects such as [lein-jlink](https://github.com/sunng87/lein-jlink) too. I'm unsure if those are suitable.

I'd really appreciate an article/tutorial, working example, or a good few hints on how to do this as I'm new to JVM also.

My project in particular would involve a business logic model "module" loaded at startup, consuming messages and producing messages in return. It's meant to be somewhat a blackbox.
An alternate route I'd like to avoid is an MQTT-style approach where distributed modules are relatively heavy standalone programs.

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 0):

In plain Java you can have use same approach as you did in C#: you develop a core and provide interfaces that can be used for extensions, then you inspect (using reflection) the Java CLASSPATH for implementations of the interface in Jar files (this is the same idea of DLLs), but the Java CLASSPATH is either an environment variable or a command-line parameter with a list of paths where to search for Jar files.

In Clojure, you have the advantage that you can distribute libraries either as compiled code or as source code which the Clojure runtime will load. I'd recommend looking into the [Deps and CLI guide](https://clojure.org/reference/deps_and_cli) because it will give you good guidance into how to:

- add dependencies on a configuration file through various means, including loading dependencies from private repos, or even a dependency in a git repo at an exact commit
- launching you code with the various switches or configuration you might need, so that you can change behaviour by editing a config file